# minimizing a given vector of components with a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Say I'm given an arbitrary vector (x,y,z). I have a dataframe with variables of the same type. (x_i,y_i,z_i)

is there a good way that I can minimize the distance (of each of the components of the given vector) with ALL of the rows  in the dataframe; where we min over the (same type variable) in the df columns?

My goal is to return the row of the vector, after it's been minimized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a vector `v` and DataFrame `df` with rows of vectors:

```
In [11]: v = pd.Series([2, 1, 0])

In [12]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]])
```

You can take their difference (i.e. `v_i - v`)

```
In [13]: df - v
Out[13]:
   0  1  2
0 -1  0  1
1  0  1  2
```

and the sum of their squares:

```
In [14]: ((df - v) ** 2).sum(1)
Out[14]:
0    2
1    5
dtype: int64
```

The smallest of which is the row-vector closest to `v`:

```
In [15]: ((df - v) ** 2).sum(1).argmin()
Out[15]: 0

In [16]: df.loc[0]
Out[16]:
0    1
1    1
2    1
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Comment: after reading the question again, not sure whether this is what's being asked... but still.

Comment: Incidentally, I'm running Python 2.7.3 and running df.loc[0] gives an Attribute error. Is there any substantive difference between these .loc vs .ix?

Comment: I think loc was introduce in 0.10 (recommend updating to latest stable), difference is loc is label based vs ineger location based ix tries to infer your meaning

Comment: Do you know how one can retrieve the n closest row-vectors to v? (I.E. not just the smallest distance?)

Comment: You could sort the Series of distances (`Out[14]`) and take the n-smallest.